# count distinct value of field on every row

Tags: sql, mysqli

**table: item_tbl**

```
|item_id |serial_code|item_name|
 ------------------------------
|   1    |  x35      | bullet  |
|   2    |  6ox      | cord    |
|   3    |  0hg      | cord    |
|   4    |  a73      | tv      |
|   5    |  lo5      | bullet  |
```

I tried to use `SELECT serial_code, item_name, COUNT(item_name) FROM item_tbl` but not what i expected of course. How can I count the distinct values of item_name to have something like:

```
|serial_code|item_name| count |
 -----------------------------
|  x35      | bullet  |  2    |
|  6ox      | cord    |  2    |
|  0hg      | cord    |  2    |
|  a73      | tv      |  1    |
|  lo5      | bullet  |  2    |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Serial_Code, count.Item_Name, Count
FROM 
     item_tbl i
     INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT Item_Name, COUNT(1) Count
         FROM item_tbl
         GROUP BY item_Name
       ) count ON i.item_Name = count.Item_Name
```

Lets see if that works.

Comment: You are on the right track with this, but in it's current form, it's syntactically wrong. You forgot the `*` or column name inside of the count ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f141/9

Comment: Corrected, the rush of getting it.